# SQL Procedure not creating

Tags: sql, .net

```
declare @Totalcount int
declare @Count nvarchar(10)

select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)

if @Totalcount is null
set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001)
else
set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001+(@Totalcount))

create procedure addemp
@EmpId nvarchar(10),
@EmpName nvarchar(50),
@EmpAddress nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
insert into NewEmp([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress]) values (@Count),(@EmpName),(@EmpAddress)
end
```

i am creating this procedure but its not working.the empid is automatic code i need to use with database when i perform the insert record on web-form i need to add one automatic code in empid

Comment: just curious, what made you go through such lengths to created `EmpId`s.  when you could simply have set that column as `identity`? it seems a waste of db operation..

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Answer (score 0):

This `select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)` will return 0

So Change

`if @Totalcount is null`

To

`if @Totalcount = 0`

Again, `if` & `else` should be followed by `Begin` `End`

```
If @Totalcount = 0
Begin
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001)
End
Else
Begin
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001+(@Totalcount))
End
```

If you want to Auto Increment you EmpId and starts from 1001 then you can set this is `IDENTITY` e.g `IDENTITY(1001,1)`. And you can avoid all the hassle of creating EmpId.

Comment: not works.. sql error when creating the procedure is "Must declare the scalar variable "@Count"."

Answer (score 0):

Your statement would be like below:

```
create procedure addemp
@EmpId nvarchar(10),
@EmpName nvarchar(50),
@EmpAddress nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
    declare @Totalcount int
    declare @Count nvarchar(10)

    select @Totalcount=(select COUNT(EmpID) from NewEmp)

    if @Totalcount is null
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001)
    else
    set @Count='A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),1001+(@Totalcount))
    insert into NewEmp([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress]) values (@Count,@EmpName,@EmpAddress)
end
```

Comment: not works..Error-"There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Comment: EmpId column is numeric OR string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create procedure addemp
    @EmpId nvarchar(10),
    @EmpName nvarchar(50),
    @EmpAddress nvarchar(50)
as 
begin       
    declare @Count nvarchar(10)

    select 
        @Count = CASE WHEN COUNT(EmpID) = 0 THEN 'A1001' 
                 ELSE 'A' + CAST(1001 + COUNT(EmpID) AS  NVARCHAR(10))
    from 
        NewEmp

    insert into NewEmp([EmpId],[EmpName],[EmpAddress]) 
    values 
    (
        @Count,
        @EmpId,
        @EmpAddress
    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really going about this all wrong. Your best option to do what you want to do is to use an `IDENTITY` column. That way SQL Server will handle generating the ID for you.

Create your table with a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    EmployeeId BIGINT CONSTRAINT PK_NewEmp PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1001,1),
    EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50),
    EmployeeAddress NVARCHAR(50),
    DisplayId AS CONCAT(N'A',EmployeeId)
);
```

The computed column `DisplayId` is simply 'A1001', 'A1002', etc.

Then, your procedure statement is completely unnecessary, but if you still want to make it you can:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddEmployee(@EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50), @EmployeeAddress NVARCHAR(50)) AS BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress) VALUES(@EmployeeName, @EmployeeAddress);
END;
```

Then, after executing the procedure twice:

```
EXEC AddEmployee N'Alice', N'123 Foo St';
EXEC AddEmployee N'Bob', N'456 Bar Rd';
```

(or alternatively, simply inserting the row without a procedure):

```
INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress) VALUES(N'Alice', N'123 Foo St'),(N'Bob', N'456 Bar Rd');
```

Then, when you run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees;
```

You will get the results:

```
EmployeeId | EmployeeName | EmployeeAddress | DisplayId
-----------|--------------|-----------------|----------
1001       | Alice        | 123 Foo St      | A1001
1002       | Bob          | 456 Bar Rd      | A1002
```